# Stopping my loop from running when a condition is met

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am trying to code a game of snap in JS. When the cards are the same, the console will log 'SNAP!' OK, but it will not stop. Am I adding the break; in at the wrong part?

```
for (mattCounter = 0; mattCounter < mattDeck.length; mattCounter++) {
  for (jamesCounter = 0; jamesCounter < jamesDeck.length; jamesCounter++) {
    if (mattDeck[mattCounter] === jamesDeck[jamesCounter]) {
      console.log('SNAP!');
      break;
    } else {
      console.log('Go again...');
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Consider putting this double for loop by itself in an appropriately named function and using `return` instead of `break`. You're only breaking out of the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The break will stop only the second for, meaning this one:

```
for (jamesCounter = 0; jamesCounter < jamesDeck.length; jamesCounter++)
```

The best option is to set a flag, initially false, and then set it to true besides making the loop break.
Then if the flag is set to true, break also the first for.

```
var flag = false;
for (mattCounter = 0; mattCounter < mattDeck.length; mattCounter++) {
    for (jamesCounter = 0; jamesCounter < jamesDeck.length; jamesCounter++) {
        if (mattDeck[mattCounter] === jamesDeck[jamesCounter]) {
            console.log('SNAP!');
            flag = true;
            break;
        } else {
            console.log('Go again...');
        }
    }
    if (flag) {
       break;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I've tried this, but it still keeps running. I want it to only log Go again until the cards match. When they match, SNAP! is to be printed and then no more loops. Instead, it keeps going.

Comment: I've cracked it! I placed the flag if statement before the 'Go again...' console log. Thank you very much for your help, sir!

Comment: glad to help!! good luck